# Filter Data according to user

Tags: java, orm, eclipselink

i working on application at which resources must be filtered according to user not role, user condition can entered by system administrator. example user1 can view customer whose balance is between 2000 and 2500 and his name start with 'a'. This condition can be enterd , altred, deleted by system administrator. I am using eclipse link.
first does the orm provide that type of filtering?
second if no, i am thinking of adding entity that contain user id and expresion , this expresion field can be added by system administrator , and i will use dynamic query to access all my data so i will add the expression to the dynamic query. is there a better way or idea to solve this problem and does this solve it or not?